# delete user from all site collections

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Currently I have this script:

```
#Config Parameters
$AdminSiteURL="adminsite"
$UserAccount = "henk@test.nl"

#Connect to SharePoint Online Tenant Admin
Connect-SPOService -URL $AdminSiteURL -Credential (Get-Credential)

#Get all Site Collections
$SitesCollections = Get-SPOSite -Template STS#0 -Limit ALL

#Iterate through each site collection
ForEach($Site in $SitesCollections)
{
    Write-host -f Yellow "Checking Site Collection:"$Site.URL

    #Get the user from site collection
    $User = Get-SPOUser -Limit All –Site $Site.URL | Where {$_.LoginName -eq $UserAccount}

    #Remove the User from site collection
    If($User)
    {
        #Remove the user from the site collection
        #Remove-SPOUser -Site $Site.URL –LoginName $UserAccount
        Write-host -f Green "`tUser $($UserAccount) has been removed from Site collection!"
    }
}
```

Our domain is @companyname.nl so for example when I search for the user test@companyname.nl it finds the users in the site collection and it deletes the user.

But when I use an external email address for example test@gmail.com which is also in the sharepoint site collection as guest it cannot find it.

Why is that?

Comment: What happens if you check the user with: `$User = Get-SPOUser –Site $Site.URL -LoginName $UserAccount -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` ?

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, to get external user, you should add #ext#@companyname.nl at the end of the external email address.

For example:

```
Get-SPOUser -Site "https://yoursite" -LoginName "test_gmail.com#ext#@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
```